# getting lastInsertId from PDO class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using this class to connect to database. It works just fine, except I couldn't get the **lastInsertId()**.

```
<?php
class connDB
{ 

public function connDB()
   {

    require_once( 'dbconfig/config.php' );

    $this->confPDO = array(
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  
                          PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, 

              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
                         );

    try
     {
     $this->dbc = new PDO( "mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname=$this->dbName", 
     $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->confPDO );
     }

   catch( PDOException $errMsg )
     {
      return false;
     }

   }

   public function exec( $sql, array $params = array() )
   {

   try
     {
     $this->stmt = $this->dbc->prepare( $sql );
      if ( count( $params ) > 0 )
        {
        foreach ( $params as $k=>$v )
                {
                $this->bind($k, $v);
                }
        }
        return $this->stmt->execute();
     }


   catch( PDOException $errMsg )
     {

     $this->dbc = null;

     return false;
     }

   }


  public function bind( $param, $value, $type = null )
   {
   if ( is_null( $type ) )
      {
      switch ( true )
             {
             // Boolen parameter
             case is_bool( $value ):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                  break;
             // Integer parameter
             case is_int( $value ):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                  break;
             // Null parameter
             case is_null( $value ):
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                  break;
             // String parameter
             default:
                  $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
             }
      }
      $this->stmt->bindValue( $param, $value, $type );
   }



  public function single()
   {

   return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }


  public function resultset()
   {

   return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }


  public function rowCount()
   {

   return $this->stmt->rowCount();
   }


 }
```

**Usage:  [SELECT]**

---

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM < table >";
 $db->exec($sql, $params);
 $rows = $db->resultset();
 foreach ($rows as $row)
       {
       echo $row['< column >'] . "\n";
       }
```

**Usage:  [INSERT]**

---

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO < table > (< column_1 >, < column_2 >, ... ) VALUES 
 (:valuename_1, 
 :valuename_2, ...)";
 $params = array(':valuename_1' => 'value', ':valuename_2' => 'value', ...);
 $db->exec($sql, $params);
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
include_once'classe.php';

 $db = new connDB();

 $sql = "INSERT INTO < table > (< column_1 >, < column_2 >, ... ) VALUES 
 (:valuename_1, 
 :valuename_2, ...)";
 $params = array(':valuename_1' => 'value', ':valuename_2' => 'value', ...);

 $db->exec($sql, $params);

 $id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

I am getting an error:

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined method connDB::lastInsertId() in
```

I've tried adding a method into the class:

```
     public function lastinsert()
   {
   // Return result
   return $this->stmt->lastInsertId();
   }
```

Then I called it like this this:

```
    $db = new connDB(); 
$id = $db->lastinsert();
```

The error this time was

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId() in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `lastInsertId()` method in your class.
You need to add it to the `connDB` class.

you need to call $dbc,  not $stmt to get lastInsertId();

```
$this->dbc->lastInsertId();
```

as this function belongs to `PDO class`, not `PDO statement class`

Also, this piece of code may cause the problem

```
catch( PDOException $errMsg )
 {

 $this->dbc = null;

 return false;
 }
}
```

Make your exec() function this way

```
public function exec( $sql, array $params = array() )
{
    $this->stmt = $this->dbc->prepare( $sql );
    foreach ( $params as $k=>$v )
    {
        $this->bind($k, $v);
    }
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. I added         public function lastinsert()
       {
       // Return result
       return $this->stmt->lastInsertId();
       }

Comment: this is obviously wrong. there is no lastInsertId() method in PDO statement class, but in PDO class.

Comment: Please post **relevant** code in your question - the code that is related to what you have tried to get last insert id and without code that has no relation to this problem.

Comment: I tried that and I am getting an error  Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object in

Comment: ok, that worked, but I have to set my columns to NULL otherwise it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Using the same database class and was able to use `lastInsertId` like this:

```
$db = new connDB();
...
$_SESSION['users_id'] = $db->dbc->lastInsertId('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the model's save function:

```
$row->save();
```

You can use:

```
return $row->save();
```

which returns the `id`